# ethers.js getAmountsOut requires tx fee?

Tags: ethers.js

I am trying to estimate how many tokens I will get for a swap using ethers.js

```
const ethers = require('ethers');

//

  const amountIn = ethers.utils.parseUnits('0.1', 'ether');
  const amounts = await router.getAmountsOut(amountIn, ['token0', 'token1']);
  const amountOutMin = amounts[1].sub(amounts[1].div(10));
  console.log(`
        =================
    tokenIn: ${amountIn.toString()} ${tokenIn} (WBNB)
    tokenOut: ${amountOutMin.toString()} ${tokenOut}
  `);
```

It worked for a while, now I get an error stating cannot estimate gas fees.

I checked my wallet and a few very small txs were sent to router.
So is ethers.js sending a tx every time it runs .getAmountOut?
If so is there a free alternative?

thanks

Comment: Which line causes the error?

Comment: hi @Ismael I see the error when running the console.log.

Comment: Do you have any more code over there or is this it? The tx could be triggered due to some other part of your code.